# Linear viscoelastic differential operators

Tags: operators, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, differential-equations

I am starting with differential operators:

$P = \sum_{i=0}^{N}p_i \cfrac{d^i}{dt^i}$

$Q = \sum_{i=0}^{N}q_i \cfrac{d^i}{dt^i}$

$p_i$ and $q_i$ are functions of time only. $K$ is a constant that represents bulk modulus.

I then have the linear viscoelastic differential operator equations:

$PS_{ij}=2Q\eta_{ij}$

$\sigma_{ii}=3K\epsilon_{ii}$

I am trying to solve this system of the two above equations for $\sigma_{ij}$. Since $S_{ij}$ is the infinitesimal deviator stress $S_{ij}=\sigma_{ij}-(1/3)\delta_{ij}\sigma_{kk}$ and $\eta_{ij}$ is defined similarly for infinitesimal strain, $\eta_{ij}=\epsilon_{ij}-(1/3)\delta_{ij}\epsilon_{kk}$, I was able to substitute these results in and get to the following:

$P\sigma_{ij}=\cfrac{3\delta_{ij}(KP-2Q)}{3}\epsilon_{kk}+2Q\epsilon_{ij}$

The book I am reading tells me that this can be further reduced to:

$\sigma_{ij}=\cfrac{3\delta_{ij}(KP-2Q)}{3P}\epsilon_{kk}+\cfrac{2Q}{P}\epsilon_{ij}$

I find this last move to be mathematical suspect. $P$ is not a constant but a differential operator; the only way to remove it from the left-hand side of the equation is to calculate an inverse operator and apply it to both sides, something I do not know how to do. Am I missing something here? Am I not using the notation correctly? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you interpret the division $1/P$ to mean the inverse operator $P^{-1}$ then are you happy with it?

Comment: While that would make mathematical sense, the notation would still be ambiguous. If $\cfrac{3\delta_{ij}(KP-2Q)}{3P}\epsilon_{kk}+\cfrac{2Q}{P}\epsilon_{ij}$ is taken to be, more explicitly, $P^{-1}(\cfrac{3\delta_{ij}(KP-2Q)}{3}\epsilon_{kk})+P^{-1}(2Q\epsilon_{ij})$, then how would you denote $\cfrac{3\delta_{ij}(KP(\epsilon_{kk})-2Q(\epsilon_{kk}))}{3P(\epsilon_{kk})}+2Q(\epsilon_{ij})/P(\epsilon_{ij})$? As a side note, does it follow that if $P$ is linear then $P^{-1}$ is linear? And under what conditions does a linear differential operator even have an inverse?